# How i can run command by run schedule and by button also?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have created commands in `kernel.php` which is running `twiceDaily()`. I also want to attach it with button so I can run this command by clicking on that button. When I click on on button it should run at that moment.

Currently, I have just created twiceDaily command I need better way to implement button idea.

kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\ResendAttachment)->twiceDaily(1, 13);
}
```

I want to run command by cron job on server and by button also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing now is scheduling a job to run twice daily.
However, you can also [manually dispatch a job](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#dispatching-jobs) to run at that instance (or as soon as a runner is free to handle your job).

You can create a controller action so that when the button is clicked, the controller dispatch the job. For example,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Jobs\ResendAttachment;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Resend attachment.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function resendAttachment(Request $request)
    {
        ResendAttachment::dispatch();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a route, for example:

```
Route::get('/resentattachment', 'YourController@resentattachment')->name('resent.attachment');
```

Call command from your controller

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function resentattachment()
    {
        Artisan::call('yourcommand');
        echo 'Sent successfully';
        //add other stuff like a success view
    }
}
```

Call this route on your button click.